# Same meaning, same pronunciation, different spelling

Tags: terminology

As you know some single words may be written in various forms, e.g.like nosy and nosey or  Noruz may be written Norooz, Narooz, Nawru, Nauruz, Nawroz, Noruz, Nohrooz, Novruz, Nauroz, Navroz.

In Persian dokme/tokme , zoqal/z̤oqal, belit/beliṭ ,...

In Linguistics we say: Noruoz is `?????` of Noruz.

Such words have same pronunciation or a very similar pronunciation. They have same origin but when are enter to another language they are written differently.

A lot of such words can be found in this forum thread: [*Multiple Spellings of the Same Word*](http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/archive/index.php/t-172645.html).

Please suggest a single word for indicated area, e.g. **Polygraph**

[image] ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym))

Comment: alternate spellings.

Comment: @jlovegren I suggested that too elsewhere, but the OP said he wanted a single term (which I doubt exists).

Comment: how about allographs?

Comment: As I said once before: They're just variant transliterations. Remember the fuss about what [the **real** spelling](http://dailycaller.com/2011/02/23/gaddafi-kaddafi-qaddafi-how-do-you-spell-the-libyan-leaders-name/) of Gaddafi's name was? It's spelled in Arabic, so it doesn't **have** a proper spelling in Latin-alphabet languages, and each has their own way of dealing with Arabic. Plus styles change. There is no special monomorphemic term for such a transcriptional mess.

Comment: @jlawler You didn't mention about the term being there or not, is it? Is there a single term?

Comment: @jlovegren [Allograph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allography) has another, broader, meaning already.

Comment: _Alternate transliteration_ is the closest to describing that situation.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: I think perhaps the two senses can coexist without too much conflict? The can be specified in special cases. After all, there is nothing in the components of the word per se that make its meaning any more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term I've heard most often in linguistic contexts is *variant*, or more fully *variant spelling*.

So, for example:

- *Nosey* is a common variant of *nosy*.
- *Favorite* and *favourite* are variants, accepted in American and British English respectively.
- Colonel Gaddafi's surname has any number of variant spellings when written in the Roman alphabet.

A Google Books search brings up plenty of examples of this in academic writing and in  textbooks, so I think it would be generally understood if you used it.